# About the random $\pm 1$ matrices

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

I was reading the paper ["On the probability that a random $\pm 1$ matrix is singular"](http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/matrices/Kahn_Komlos_Szemeredi_1995.pdf). In the paper the author defined the following notations:

$M_n$: a random $n\times n$ matrix with i.i.d entries such that each entry takes values $\pm 1$ with equal probability.

$p(a)$: for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, define 
$$p(a)=\mathbb{P}(\epsilon^Ta=0),$$
where $\epsilon$ is a vector drawn uniformly from $\{\pm 1\}^n$.

$E_a$: for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $E_a$ is the event "$M_na=0$".

$L_i$: the event "the $i-$th row of $M_n$ is a linear combination of the other $n-1$ rows".

Then the author claimed that for any $p_0\in(0,1)$ and $1\leq i\leq n$ we have 
$$\mathbb{P}([\cup\{E_a: p(a)\leq p_0\}]\cap L_i)\leq p_0.$$

This is where I got confused. The author didn't provide a proof. I am having trouble to convince myself that the above inequality is true. Anybody willing to help? I will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean $p(a) = \mathbb P(\epsilon^T a = 0)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Exactly, I'll fix that.

Comment: The proof for that claim given in the original source is this sentence that follows it: "Indeed, $p_0$ is an upper bound on the probability of this event conditioned on *any* values in the other $n-1$ rows, since for such matrices the set $\{a:p(a)\leq p_0, Ma=0\}$ is determined already by those $n-1$ rows." So I guess the task is to unpack that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo the following claim (which is true for low dimensions, and is quite plausible, but I  didn't find a proof), it can be done.

> Claim: A subspace generated by $k$ linearly independent $(\pm1)$ vectors contains $2^k$ $(\pm1)$ vectors.

First note that this implies that if $a$ is orthogonal to a $k$-codimensional subspace generated by $(\pm1)$ vectors, then $p(a)\geq2^{-k}$. Indeed, by the claim, there is at least $2^{n-k}$ $(\pm1)$ vectors that $a$ is orthogonal to, so there is at least $2^{-k}$ probability of selecting one of them.

A second consequence of the claim is that, given a $k$-codimensional subspace generated by $(\pm1)$ vectors, the probability of a uniformly selected $(\pm1)$ vector to fall into this subspace is $2^{-k}$.

Then denoting the codimension of the subspace generated by the rows $1,2,\ldots,i-1,i+1,\ldots,n$ by $C$, the above two observations give

$$
\mathbb{P}([\cup\{E_a: p(a)\leq p_0\}]\cap L_i\,|\,C=k) \leq
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(\cup\{E_a: p(a)\leq p_0\}\,|\,C=k)=0,  & \text{if $p_0<2^{-k}$} \\
\mathbb{P}(L_i\,|\,C=k)=2^{-k}\leq p_0, & \text{if $p_0\geq2^{-k}$.}
\end{cases}
$$